# fixing retrived paths from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with MySQL , that when I insert a path-to-a-directory in it , it automatically drops every '/' or '\' in the path string (which is apparently called canonized version of the path). when I retrieve the path using PHP I get something like this

```
C:wampwwwnamaCar_Images91Thumbs
```

Is there any PHP function that fixes this problem ? I want to use the retrieved path for the HTML image source but it doesn't work

Tnx

Comment: You're looking for `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: I'm using PDO , is it available in PDO too ?

Comment: On PDO you're looking either for [PDO::quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) or better yet - use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Do you use prepared statements?

Comment: No , the structure of the application did not let me to do that !

Comment: Could you show us, how are you inserting path?

Comment: Unfortunately the PDO::quote was no help either!

Comment: $path='c/: blabla' ; $query ="insert into thumb_table set thumb_front='$path';